# Synchronized calls across different computers

Tags: linux, networking, language-agnostic, synchronization, clock

I have three Linux boxes, each running my program.

The program needs to call a certain callback at regular intervals, and each call must happen at the *exact same time* across the three boxes. I don't need any other synchronization except for the calls.

If it helps, the three boxes have their clocks synchronized by NTP (one of the boxes is the master).

Is there a way to accomplish this with good precision? Preferably non Linux specific. To make things simple, the callback must be called each N ms even if a previous call hasn't completed yet.

Comment: The boxes are in a network, but the connection has important latency and packet loss so it's not reliable.

Answer (score 1):

How about you send a request to execute the function far enough ahead of time including a timestamp when the function should be executed? The receiving application would sleep/wait the remaining time (some time is lost due to latency), then execute the function at the precise timestamp you requested.

If the called function itself takes longer than your interval, you should probably consider using threads. If the function executes quickly but transfer of the results takes longer then you should get away with something like `select()` without additional threads.

Comment: This seems like the right way to go, in the sense that it's the best you're going to get. But if the connection has latency (as the OP says), the NTP won't get the machines exactly in sync. As far as I can see, you're screwed by this point: nothing can guarantee to sync the time exactly with arbitrary and unpredictable latency.

Comment: It does have latency, but it's not very variable so NTP synchronized pretty good (< 3ms offset). As long as the calls are done within 10ms it's okay. Will try this!